# How to move wedge directly away from center?

Tags: objects, transforms

See attached picture. How do I move the wedge(s) directly away from the "circle" center, along the same plane?
[image: mesh objects to transform]

Comment: Try changing Transform Orientation, make it to Local

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is with the *Manipulate Origins* option:

[image]

1. Center the origin of the wedge(s) by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*> [Origin to Geometry](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/introduction.html#object-centers)*.
2. Enable *Manipulate Center Points* (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>`,`</kbd>)
3. Set the [*Pivot Point*](http://blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html) to [*3D cursor*](http://blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/pivot_point/3d_cursor.html) (<kbd>`.`</kbd>). Ensure the cursor is in the center of the circle.
4. In object mode with the wedge(s) selected, scale them outward (<kbd>S</kbd>).

This works for multiple wedges at once:

[image]

Comment: Bravo. How does one now "disconnect" from the center point obligation?

Comment: @NeverGiveUp What do you mean?

Comment: Nevermind. I moved the wedge randomly and forgot to move the cursor.

Answer (score 4):

You know that your wedge is 60°.
So first set the pivot point to *3D cursor*, then rotate the wedge in edit mode 30° (so it is straight along the Y axis). Then in object mode mode rotate it back 30° to its original spot.

Then when you change the Transform Orientation to *Local* you can move the wedge out from the center.

[image: animated gif]

This works for multiple wedges at once
[image: animated gif]

Comment: I'm using percentages of the circle, not degrees to make a pie chart, so conversions are tedious (python add-on please). I had also tried the Normal approach/method but wasn't working for me.

Comment: @NeverGiveUp conversions are not hard. Just type right in to the rotation field `X*360` where X is the decimal value for your percent. Same goes for rotation it in edit mode.

Comment: So I have a mesh circle top view. How to divide that in X faces for N percentages?

Answer (score 3):

Select one piece and enter the *Edit Mode*. Change the transformation type to ***Normal***. You can now change the place of the pieces without moving the origin point.
[image]